# Is it possible to store files of a folder in dynamic array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to find same name files in two folders.
I used File and listed names of file in two array list.
then i added common name files in two folders to a new arraylist and going to apply diff to find if these files are different or not.

As i have only stored name of files in Array List, i can't apply operation on those files directly.

Someone told me that by the use of dynamic array one can save files in Java...

My code till now with help of some great friends :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class ListFiles1 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        String path1 = "C:\\Users\\hi\\Downloads\\IIT Typing\\IIT Typing"; 

        String path2 = "C:\\Users\\hi\\Downloads\\IIT Typing\\IIT Typing"; 

        File folder1 = new File(path1);
        File folder2 = new File(path2);

        String[] f1=folder1.list();

        File[] listOfFiles1 = folder1.listFiles(); 
        File[] listOfFiles2 = folder2.listFiles(); 

        ArrayList<String> fileNames1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> fileNames2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles1.length; i++) 
        {

            if (listOfFiles1[i].isFile()) 
            {
                fileNames1.add(listOfFiles1[i].getName());
               // System.out.println(f1[i] + " is a file");
            }

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < listOfFiles2.length; j++) 
        {

            if (listOfFiles2[j].isFile()) 
            {
                fileNames2.add(listOfFiles2[j].getName());
            }
        }

    ArrayList<String> commonfiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles1.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < listOfFiles2.length; j++) 
            {
            String tempfilename1;
            String tempfilename2;
            tempfilename1=fileNames1.get(i);
            tempfilename2 = fileNames2.get(j);
            if(tempfilename1.equals(tempfilename2))
                {
                commonfiles.add(tempfilename1);
                System.out.println(commonfiles);
                }
            }
    }            

    }
}
```

Comment: you have direct method to get list of file names : fileObject.list() , returns a String[]

Comment: You're the laziest person I've ever seen. You haven't written any code yourself; you keep asking questions crudely copy-pasting people's answers and then expecting more help to put it together.

Comment: @Boann : Kindly read my question i specified that i did it with help of my frnds.... 
be good don't search for evil... the ultimate journey ends when one sees inside himself

Comment: @Shubham Try to do something, anything, yourself.

Comment: @Boann : i am trying... I made the common array on my own.... 
I am fearful....this thing is really out of my minds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather then having an ArrayList of Strings of the file names, just have an ArrayList of Files

```
List<File> filesList1 = Arrays.asList(folder1.listFiles());
List<File> filesList2 = Arrays.asList(folder2.listFiles());
```

Then when comparing if they have the same name then do your check of if it is a file and has the same name, then you have the reference to the File object and not just the name so you can read the files and see if they are the same.

```
for (File f1 : filesList1)
{
    if(f1.isFile())
    {
        for (File f2 : filesList2) 
        {
            if(f2.isFile() && f1.getName().equals(f2.getName))
            {
                commonfiles.add(f1.getName());
                System.out.println(f1.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This could be done way more efficiently with sets though

Comment: I originally thought of loading the collections this way, but it won't work - you need to load the filenames (and maybe File.list() will work for that - but I'm not sure if that returns the full paths, or just the filename)

Comment: The only Error I made was casting the list, which is now edited.

Comment: Ah - I see what you intended now - yeah, much more efficient to use sets ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your question actually is here, but I suggested that you use:

```
Set<String> dir1Files = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> dir2Files = new HashSet<String>();

// load the sets with the filenames by iterating the File.listFiles() value, and using File.isFile() and File.getName() - just like your existing code

dir1Files.retainAll(dir2Files);

// now dir1Files contains the filenames that are the same in both directories
```

And if you need to work with the file itself, just recreate the File object:

```
File dir1File = new File(folder1, filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
public class FileNameMatcher 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        File folder1 = new File("C:/Users/pappu/Downloads");
        File folder2 = new File("C:/Users/pappu");
        for(String fileFromFolderOne:folder1.list())
        {
            for(String fileFromFolderTwo:folder2.list())
            {
                if(fileFromFolderOne.equals(fileFromFolderTwo))
                {
                    System.out.println("match found");
                    System.out.println("file name is ===>>>"+fileFromFolderOne);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```